# Does CALayer shouldRasterize propagate to all sublayers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, calayer

If I set shouldRasterize = YES on a CALayer, do I have to set it on each of the sublayers as well if I wanted the whole hierarchy to be flattened for better animation performance?

I'm asking because when I set shouldRasterize = YES on my root layer and enable "Color Blended Layers" in Instruments, all the sublayers are still there and marked as blended. It's not flattening anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting `shouldRasterize` does not do quite what you are thinking it does. In order to composite the look of the parent view, rasterized or not, it has to check subviews to see if they are `opaque` or transparent. When child objects are `opaque`, they do not need to be blended. When they are transparent, the view needs to be blended with whatever is behind them (or higher in the hierarchy).

So, `shouldRasterize` will not affect the green/red you see using Instruments. In order to have everything green, you'll need to not use transparency and have all your child objects be `opaque`. Sometimes its unavoidable to still have red areas depending on your design. The instrument is just there to help you optimize ones that *could* be `opaque` and reduce the amount of blending the GPU has to do.

Edit: 
To explain further, suppose you have a `UILabel` and its sitting on top of a photo. You only want to see the text and not its background color, so you set its `backgroundColor` to clear, and the `opaque` property to NO. In instruments, this will now appear red. The GPU has to blend this transparency over the image behind it, performing two draw operations instead of one.

If we had set `opaque` to `YES` and gave it a solid background color, the view would now show up green in instruments because it didn't have to blend that view with any other view.

So, whether the layer is rasterized or not, it still has to composite its child views so `shouldRasterize` really has no effect either way on what you see in Instruments.

Comment: Would setting shouldRasterize to YES improve animation performance though?

Comment: It depends on how you are performing your animations. If you are using the animation methods on `UIView`, one of the animation options is to allow rendered content of the views its animating. This is off by default, which means the animation will take a snapshot of the view and animate that. So in that case rendering would not really be affected.

If you're using CAAnimations, you will get a performance increase by setting `shouldRasterize`, because the animation will only animated the rasterized layer, and not ask it to draw each frame of the animation loop.

Comment: This is a great answer but I'm still wondering about the answer to the original question. Although "Color Blended Layers" is about something else, shouldRasterize is relevant to "Color Hits Green and Misses Red" and "Color Offscreen-rendered Yellow", which are both useful for debugging animation performance. But how?